# How to use info on substring position from one file to extract substring from another file (loop, bash)

Tags: bash, loops, awk, grep, substring

I'm trying quite hard to write a script that "loopingly" extracts substrings from one file, while getting the information on where to cut from another file. I'm working in bash on MobaXterm. I have the file cut_positions.txt, which is tab delimited and shows name, start point, end point, length, comment:

```
k141_20066  103484  104617  1133    phnW  
k141_20841  13200   14324   1124    phnW  
k141_23852  69  452 383 phnW  
k141_32328  1   180 179 phnW
```

and the string_file.txt with the name (it would be no problem to remove/add the ">" in one of the files) and the string (the original strings are way longer, up to 1.000.000 characters):

```
>k141_10671 CCTTCCCCCACACGCCGCTCTTCCGCTCTTGCTGGCC  
>k141_10707 AGGCGGTATCAGACCTTGCCGCAACACTAAGCCCAGTAACGCTGTCGCCCTTATATCTGA  
>k141_11190 CTTTTGTGACAGTGCAGGGCAATGGTGGATTTATCAGTATCGGGCAGAA  
>k141_1479  AGCCGACAGCAGCGCCGAGGGCACATAATCCGATGACACGATGTCCAAAAGATCCGCCTCGGC
```

Now I want to use the input from the cut_positions.txt. I want to use the first column to match the right line, then the second column as start point of the substring and the fourth column as length of the substring. This should be done with all lines in cut_positions.txt and written to a new out.txt. To get closer I tried (with my original data):

```
➤ grep ">k141_28027\b" test_out_one_line.txt | awk '{print substr($2,57251,69)}'
TCACTTGAGCGCAATTATTCGCTCTCCGGCGGCGTCAGCATCAGCCTGATCATGCGTCACCAAAAGTGT
```

which worked well as handmade way. I figured out as well how to access the different elements in cut_positions.txt (here the first row in the second column):

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==1{print $2}' cut_positions.txt
```

but I can't figure out how to turn this into a loop, as I don't know how to connect the different redirections, piping steps and so on that I used for the small steps. Any help is very much appreciated (and tell me, if you need more sample data)

thanks
crazysantaclaus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script should work for you:

*cut.awk*

```
# We are reading two files: pos.txt and strings.txt
# NR is equal to FNR as long as we are reading the
# first file.
NR==FNR{
    pos[">"$1]=$2 # Store the startpoint in an array pos (indexed by $1)
    len[">"$1]=$4 # Store the length in an array len (indexed by $1)
    next # skip the block below for pos.txt
}

# This runs on every line of strings.txt
$1 in pos {
    # Extract a substring of $2 based on the position and length
    # stored above
    key=$1
    mod=substr($2,pos[key],len[key])
    $2=mod
    print # Print the modified line
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -f cut.awk pos.txt strings.txt
```

---

One **important** thing to mention. `substr()` assumes strings to start at index `1` - in opposite to most programming languages where strings start at index `0`. If the positions in `pos.txt` are `0` based, the `substr()` must become:

```
mod=substr($2,pos[key]+1,len[key])
```

---

I recommend to test it with simplified, meaningful versions of:

*pos.txt*

```
foo  2  5  3    phnW  
bar  4  5  1    phnW
test 1  5  4    phnW
```

and *strings.txt*

```
>foo 123456  
>bar 123456
>non 123456
```

Output:

```
>foo 234
>bar 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm not really sure how it works...I just ran it on a small subsample and it gives me the remaining strings from     strings.txt? I'm sorry if I didn't used it correctly, but what I need is the substring extracted from     strings.txt. I also should have said, that the two files are not identical in terms of the first column. I have the pos.txt (maybe 1000 line) to get the matching substrings out of strings.txt (100.000 lines), therefore the weird grep part in my trials. Sorry for the inconveniance!

Comment: I see. Updated the answer.

Comment: Hey hek2mgl, that is really close (I guess), but sadly not it yet. I fear I'm using terms wrong here? When I said "but what I need is the substring extracted from strings.txt" I meant the exact opposite of your output...so I'm interested in the part that you are getting rid of...isn't that the substring? BTW: keeping the names in front of the string as you showed in your output would be perfect, but if that makes things to complicated (more then they already are) I think I could also merge it afterwards with the names pos.txt...

Comment: I thought you want the original string *without* the substr. It's simple to chnage that (that was how was before) ... Moment

Comment: @crazysantaclaus Srry, had a super-busy day. I'll look at this tomorrow.

Comment: don't worry, I know this problem a lot ;-)

Comment: Oh missed you. Again very busy day. Don't give up to remind me if I should miss it again. I'll fix it - for science! ;) ...

Comment: that would be perfect...for science ;-)

Comment: wow, just checked it, it works perfect! To understand it better: you are not using a loop, it is more a like an input list or array, right? I find it very confusing with $1/$2 etc sometimes being a variable and sometimes adressing a column. "pos" and "len" and "key" are not fixed terms, but user variables you set? One more question: how are the "names" from file1 and file2 are compared? Thanks a lot, that saves me weeks of stupid work!

Comment: `pos` and `len` are lookups (indexed arrays) which are indexed by the *name*. I fill them when iterating trough `pos.txt`, which needs to the first filename passed to awk. The index in those arrays is the key to correlated *names*. `$1, ... $N` will always be used to address *fields* in `awk`. They are not used to address variables. I'm using a quite idiomatic `awk` style which is efficient but  probably hard to understand for beginners. I recommend to start learning `awk` from scratch, let's say using this [O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do). ...

Comment: Having good `awk` skills, learned from scratch, will very much bump your opportunities in every day work which such text based (fasta?) files to a new level.

Comment: PS: Not to forget, there is also this https://www.amazon.com/Effective-awk-Programming-Arnold-Robbins/dp/0596000707

Comment: ah sorry and another question ;-) what happens if I have mutliple queries on the same string? so like 3 lines in pos.txt would refer to the same line in strings.txt, but result in different substrings. at the moment I'm not getting all the substrings I would expect, also sorting does not change the outcome. I will check on that with unique queries in the pos.txt

Comment: That's a bit beyond the scope of this question and what stackoverflow is meant for. I recommend to get truly familiar with the program I gave you, learn awk in general, and go and modify it to your needs. If you stumble upon a particular problem which you are not able to solve on your own feel free to ask another question here and show what you tried to solve it and what does not work as expected.

Comment: yeah I also had the feeling that this is getting too much...so thank you very much for your help and your literature suggestions. awk skills seem  to be very convient for sequence data ;) I will try get one the books...have a nice weekend!