# how to use awk to add specific values to a column based on numeric ranges

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to add a column to my file `coverage_file` based on numbers within my `bed_file`. In my `coverage_file` I have positions in the second column and the `bed_file` contains position ranges from second to third column together with a name in column 4. I would like to add the corresponding name for each position to the `coverage_file` within the range of the `bed_file` and also have it numbered, so I can distinguish between multiple position ranges on the same object (contig). Hope my example data makes is clearer:

```
#example data

#coverage file looks like:

#k141_xxx.xx are contigs (long sequences of DNA), where different genes can be found on.
#the second column is the current position on the individual contig
#the third column is the coverage on this position (not important here)
#the fourth column is the sample where the data comes from: A1..7 and B8..10

k141_102288 298 5 A4
k141_102288 298 5 A5
k141_102288 298 5 B8
k141_102288 298 5 B9
k141_102288 299 5 A4
k141_102288 299 5 A5
k141_102288 299 5 B9
k141_102288 300 5 A5
k141_102288 301 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8226 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8227 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8228 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8229 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8230 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8231 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8232 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8233 5 A5
k141_102511.0 8234 5 A5
k141_102511.0 9129 5 A6
k141_102511.0 9207 5 A6
k141_102511.0 9275 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9276 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9277 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9278 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9279 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9280 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9281 5 A7
k141_102511.0 9282 5 A7
```

---

```
#bed file looks like this
# the bed file shows the start $2 and end $3 position of a gene $4 on the contigs $1
k141_102288 2   301 phnE
k141_102511.0   7890    8807    phnE
k141_102511.0   8814    10400   phnE
```

---

```
#proposed output (note the two different regions of phnE on k141_102511.0)
k141_102288 298 5 A4    phnE_001
k141_102288 298 5 A5    phnE_001
k141_102288 298 5 B8    phnE_001
k141_102288 298 5 B9    phnE_001
k141_102288 299 5 A4    phnE_001
k141_102288 299 5 A5    phnE_001
k141_102288 299 5 B9    phnE_001
k141_102288 300 5 A5    phnE_001
k141_102288 301 5 A5    phnE_001
k141_102511.0 8226 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8227 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8228 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8229 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8230 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8231 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8232 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8233 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 8234 5 A5 phnE_002
k141_102511.0 9129 5 A6 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9207 5 A6 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9275 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9276 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9277 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9278 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9279 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9280 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9281 5 A7 phnE_003
k141_102511.0 9282 5 A7 phnE_003
```

I tried to make use of a former similar question I had, but still can't figure out how to make it work: [How to use info on substring position from one file to extract substring from another file (loop, bash)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153483/how-to-use-info-on-substring-position-from-one-file-to-extract-substring-from-an)

any suggestions?
EDIT:
I tried to go with suggestion no. 2 by @Nic3500, but I can't get it to run. I have an unexpected token in the last line. This is what I came up with so far:

```
#!bin/bash

# We are reading two files: coverage_file.txt and intersect.bed
# NR is equal to FNR as long as we are reading the
# first file.
# Store the positions in an array current_position from the coverage file (indexed by $1)
# go to bed file
# store the start and end positions and the gene names in similar arrays
# if current_position is between start_pos and end_pos, print additionally gene name 

awk 'NR==FNR{current_position[$1]=$2} 
NR==FNR{next}
{start_pos[$1]=$2;end_pos[$1]=$3;gene_name[$1]=$4}
{if(current_position[$1] >= start_pos[$1]) && (current_position[$1] <= `end_pos[$1]){ print $1,$2,$3,$4,gene_name[$1]}}' coverage_file.txt intersect.bed > test.txt`
```

Comment: Suggestions: get rid of the range numbering issue.  Create a temporary bed file, and change the name with the numbering right in there.  This way, your numbering just becomes the number of the line, and can be implemented easily with a counter and a loop.

Comment: Suggestion 2: loop on your `coverage_file`, line per line.  Extract the second item in the line.  With that second item, loop on your `bed_file`, line per line again.  Extract the second and third elements for the lines.  If (`coverage_file`.seconditem >= `bed_file`.secondelement) AND (`coverage_file`.seconditem <= `bed_file`.thirdelement) then add the 4th element of the `bed_file` line.

Comment: @Nic3500: thanks for your hints, I tried suggestion 2 but can't get it to run, any ideas on improvement?

Comment: I am not an awk guru, I would not use awk personnaly (though this is more related to my lack of knowledge than the quality of the tool!).  Others will have to chime in at this point ;-)

Comment: @hek2mgl: thanks anyway, maybe some awk-experienced guys who already helped me come to my rescue ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 $ awk 'NR==FNR{start[NR]=$2; end[NR]=$3; key[$1,$2]=$4 sprintf("_%03d",NR); next}
           {for(i in start)
              {s=start[i];
               if(s<=$2 && $2<=end[i] && ($1,s) in key) print $0,key[$1,s]}}' bed coverage
```

**Explanation** While reading the first file (`NR==FNR` section), create arrays indexed with line number to start and end of the ranges. We need to correlate the ranges with the key, so create a map indexed with key and start for each range; here also the opportunity to create the indexed tag using the line number counter and the last field as the label, format the number to zero padded three digits.

For processing the second file (second statement now), we iterate through all the starts find the matching end and verify the key,range start is a valid combination, print the line with the formatted suffix added.

This can be made more efficient by indexing the start values with the key, but will complicate the code. If your "bed" file is not huge, shouldn't be a problem.  Also intentionally prints all the matching entries, not the first one to validate that the ranges do not overlap.  Otherwise, do the validation offline and improve speed by breaking after the first match/print.  Also if the start values are sorted, loop can be exited early when the start range is missed.

Comment: that works very well, thanks! But I don't understand exactly what you are doing, could you comment a little bit more?

Comment: you have to ask more specific questions!  I think it reads very well if you know the basic concepts in `awk`.  The generic information can be found everywhere including this site.

Comment: true, well ok, I do not understand the role of start/end[NR] in the first line? Is key the "link" between both files? And I don't get the last if condition && (&1,s), I don't see what is checked there? Would be great if you could add a sentence to that.

Comment: perfect, thanks! I will add some "print" statements to the loop to see what is exactly happening "inside"

Comment: sorry to bother you once more, I think I got most of your  code now...but why do we have  `key[$1,$2]=$4` in the first line? Why do you assign column 4 from the bed file to two columns? Is it maybe to use key[$2] as field where the output of  `sprintf("_%03d",NR)` is assigned to? When I print out the content of `key[$1]` or `key[$2]` it is blank and `print key[$1,$2]` returns only one value? That confuses me ;-) I tried to read into it, but I it is problematic to find specific information in the vast amount of awk-docs (I even have the book). So again, sorry for being slow today...

Comment: `key` map contains the $1 and range start as the (composite) key and the value you want to attach to the match "phnE_00x" as the value.  `$4 sprint()` is one value, string concatenation without any delimiter.  Providing part of the key wont work as key[$1], you should have `key[$1,s]` where `s` is the corresponding start value assigned in the first statement.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try to use this approach for another scenario and will see, if I got it. I'm reading this articles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key https://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/MDBS01CD/page_19.htm to understand this "key" concept