# how to interprete and optimize awk arrays for matching and modifying two files' common column

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

After trying the whole day to get more into awk and arrays, my code now roughly does (I think) what I was hoping for: matching two files based on a common column and then adding another column from file 1 to file 2. This has been asked previously and I tried many different versions, but that it now works is more coincidental I have the impression.

People already tried to help me in related cases

([how to use awk to add specific values to a column based on numeric ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050245/how-to-use-awk-to-add-specific-values-to-a-column-based-on-numeric-ranges) and [print output of user-defined function in awk gives unexpected token error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067678/print-output-of-user-defined-function-in-awk-gives-unexpected-token-error) and more)

but the different solutions collided in my head and now there is a mess.

Though my code is somewhat working, it now prints out matching lines twice (?) and it is also quite slow. I'm sure there is a lot to optimize, could you give some hints on what I'm actually doing and how to improve it? This is now only for one pair of files, I have about a thousand of these pairs.

contig_lengths_cut.txt (300.000 lines):

```
 k141_157024 1 1011
k141_158290 1 462
k141_158291 1 1648
k141_158292 1 329
k141_158293 1 534
k141_158294 1 497
k141_158295 1 418482
k141_186288 1 324
k141_186289 1 340
k141_186290 1 390
k141_186291 1 206156
k141_186292 1 491
k141_186293 1 759
k141_186294 1 4885
k141_186295 1 2736
k141_185742 1 377
k141_185743 1 6775
k141_185744 1 301
```

gene_length.txt (50 to 300 lines)

```
k141_185743 1184 gene=phnM_10
k141_186291 1247 gene=phnM_11
k141_186291 1226 gene=phnM_12
k141_157024 350 gene=phnM_9
k141_158295 1160 gene=phnM_10
k141_158295 1145 gene=phnM_11
k141_247338 410 gene=phnM_1
```

my code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { 
            contig[$1]=$3; next}; 
                {for (k in contig) 
                    if ($3 ~ contig[k]) print $0, contig[$1] }' 
contig_lengths_cut.txt gene_length.txt
```

current output is:

```
#with the updated data it is not working at all, if I add more lines to the #sample data, it works again...something is going spectacularly wrong
```

my desired output is:

```
k141_185743 1184 gene=phnM_10 6775
k141_186291 1247 gene=phnM_11 206156
k141_186291 1226 gene=phnM_12 206156
k141_157024 350 gene=phnM_9 1011
k141_158295 1160 gene=phnM_10 418482
k141_158295 1145 gene=phnM_11 418482    
#k141_247338 410 gene=phnM_1 #no match, don't print
```

I assume that `contig[$1]=$3` means (only for the first file) that the first column of file is used as index and the third column as assigned value?

and for all such elements in the array `contig`, the third column from the second file is used for matching? Which would not make too much sense in my view. But if I use the first column, I get 100s of identical entries, whereas as shown I get the desired number of lines.

Finally I print the whole line of the second file + the index column of the array, which represents the third column of the first file, correct?

Sorry for the mess, please help me to understand what I'm doing here so I don't have to ask that frequent anymore ;-)

Comment: @anubhava: I added the current and desired output

Comment: @EdMorton: Of course, I'm just worried that a shortened subset might hide additional properties of my data so a solution might be incomplete. But you are correct, I will shorten the data and try to keep all variabilities

Comment: @anubhava: good point, I just took some lines from existent files...now I selected some lines that fit together...it is just that my script is not returning output at all anymore...so the matching was probably completely wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input samples don't provide enough data to test and match your output.  But, I think I got what your issue is.  You're looking for a regex match of values instead of an exact match on keys.  If you change your script to

```
awk 'NR==FNR {contig[$1]=$3; next}                    
     $1 in contig {print $0, contig[$1]}' contig_lengths_cut.txt gene_length.txt
```

should work fine.  However, it's not tested due to lack of testable data.

In terms of speed, if your files are not sorted, this is as fast as it will get.  You can perhaps split the file1 into chunks do a parallel run for all file1 chunks against file2 and combine the results.

If you want to debug your original code, add `contig[k]` to the print statement.

Comment: did you try this script?

Comment: I just ran it on the full dataset, works perfect and is also fast (again). To understand what you did: is `$1 in contig` referring to the same column as `contig[$1]` before? As this would be the length of the contig, which is not present in the other input file. So I don't see how you can make a match between the two files here?

Comment: `contig` array/map is filled up with file1 data, then queried with the key from file2.  The key is what joins both files.  These are nothing to do with the length of the array/map.

Comment: ok, last try, I promise: `NR==FNR {contig[$1]=$3; next}` takes input from the first file, uses the first column as index and the third column as value. The $1 in the next line refers to the first column of the second file and `$1 in contig` checks whether the entry is also present in the map from the first file. If yes, the current line from file 2 and the corresponding value from the map are printed? Thanks for bringing me close to understanding!

Comment: Bingo! you got it.